# Range.Find a value from a separate workbook not working - code check

Tags: excel, vba

tl;dr:  Running a range.find function on a reference workbook doesn't seem to find text that's definitely there.  Please critique my code.

My current goal is to have Textbox B of Userform automatically populated based on user input for Textbox A.  I'm trying to make that work by automatically searching a reference workbook for the Textbox A (user input) string and returning a value from an offset cell.

I finally have the search running without vomiting an error at me, but it can't seem to find text that's clearly present.  My code:

```
Function findSLINCalc(calc As String)

'Variables
Dim calcWkbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim slinCell As Excel.Range
Dim lCalc As Excel.Worksheet

Set calcWkbk = Excel.Workbooks("New COR Calculations.xlsx")
Set lCalc = calcWkbk.Sheets(1)

'Search the calculation spreadsheet for SLIN
If Not lCalc.Range("A1:A100").find(calc) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "I found it!"
    findSLINCalc = lCalc.Range("A1:A100").find(calc).Offset(1, 10).Value
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing there!"
End If

End Function
```

```
Private Sub SLINTB_AfterUpdate()

findSLINCalc (Me.SLINTB.Value)

End Sub
```

I'm reasonably certain I'm calling the function incorrectly in my subroutine.  Even so, running this code as is only gives me the "Nothing there!" message box.  Surely it would give me the other one if it found something, right?

Other possibly pertinent info:

1. The reference workbook will vary in length but not format or file name/location.
2. The string I'm searching for will be part of a merged cell (columns A+B).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Specify the other parameters for `Range.Find` - `LookIn` and `LookAt` and maybe `MatchCase` too.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `Me.SLINTB.Value` with `Me.SLINTB.Text`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies!  @BigBen I played around with all three of those (LookIn:= xlValues, LookAt:= xlPart, MatchCase:= False) and got the same result.

Comment: @jclasley Interesting idea, I'll have to give that a go tomorrow.

Comment: Also if this is a function, you should capture the result, e.g. `Dim theResult as String`, `theResult = findSLINCalc(Me.SLINTB.Value)`.

Comment: @BigBen  Ah, of course!  y=F(x).  Makes so much sense.  Thanks!  I'm very new at VBA so that's super helpful.

Comment: See if [This](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) helps?